# Calling a python function from overrided write method gives maximum recursion depth exceeded error in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-9

Previously same question is asked. but it was about accessing field from write function. My problem is to call the python function..

My code is as follows..

```
@api.multi
def write(self,values):
    self.call_fun()//calling python function//
    if self.pool['res.users'].has_group(self._cr, self.env.user.id, 'stpi.group_stpi_manager'):
        pass
    else:
        if self.create_uid != self.env.user:
            raise Warning('You can not able to edit this document as this is not your record')
    return super(book_meeting, self).write(values)
```

The error i am getting is

Comment: can u post the trackback?

Comment: Show the rest of the code. What class is this a part of?

Comment: This function and fields are the part of the class book_meeting